# SQL Android Query formulation with multiple conditions

Tags: android, sql, parameters

I am writing an android application that is trying to pull data from a database based on two separate criteria.

The fields of workout and exercise are both strings in the database.  I want to return a cursor with only those rows that satisfy BOTH criteria.  Oh and I would also like it to be sorted in date order...

```
public Cursor graphQuery(String exercise, String workout) {
     Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS,       
         KEY_REPS_FEEL, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT_FEEL}, "KEY_WORKOUT=" + workout + "AND" +  
         "KEY_EXERCISE=" + exercise, null , null, null, KEY_DATE); 

     return cursor;
}
```

I am a new android coder and would appreciate the help!

Comment: You could make your code work by quoting the `workout` and `exercise` in the `selection` String. However, this is not the preferred approach. See my answer for how to properly use the `selectionArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `selection` and `selectionArgs`:

```
public Cursor graphQuery(String exercise, String workout) {
     Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS,       
         KEY_REPS_FEEL, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT_FEEL}, "KEY_WORKOUT = ? AND KEY_EXERCISE = ?",
         new String[] { workout, exercise },
         null,
         null,
         KEY_DATE); 

     return cursor;
}
```

Notice how the `selection` `String` has `?`s inplace of actual values and the actual values are passed in as a `String[]` and in the `selectionArgs` paramter. SQLite will replace those `?`s with the values from the `String[]` `selectionArgs`.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to figure out how to use the ?.  I had given up on those.  Appears I was pretty much just wrong on the quotations.

Thanks for the quick response!  I still have a force close to figure out but at least I know the code is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There are spaces missing around "AND" --> " AND ".:

Long answer: Please use parameter markers - you will see missing spaces immediately then:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] { KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS,       
         KEY_REPS_FEEL, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT_FEEL }, "KEY_WORKOUT=? and KEY_EXERCISE=?", new String[] { workout, exercise }, null, null, KEY_DATE);
```